# Python - Netifaces вывод значений

Tags: python

Нашел в интернете код, позволяющий с помощью `netifaces`, получать `IP адрес` и другую информацию о сетевом подключении.
Пытаюсь написать код, получающий `IP адрес, broadcast, subnet, hwaddr` и другое

```
import netifaces

def test():
    interfaces = netifaces.interfaces()
    public_ip_list = []
    broadcast = []
    subnet = []
    hwaddr = []
    for interface in interfaces:
        # Only keep ethX interfaces.
        if not interface.startswith("en"):
            continue
        # Discard interfaces that are up but without any IPs.
        addrs = netifaces.ifaddresses(interface).get(netifaces.AF_INET)
        addrs1 = netifaces.ifaddresses(interface).get(netifaces.AF_LINK)
        if not addrs or addrs1:
            continue
        bs = [addr.get("broadcast") for addr in addrs]
        ips = [addr.get("addr") for addr in addrs]
        mask = [addr.get("netmask") for addr in addrs]
        hw = [addr.get("addr") for addr in addrs1]
        try:
            public_ip_list.append(ips[0])
            broadcast.append(bs[0])
            subnet.append(mask[0])
            hwaddr.append(hw[0])
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return public_ip_list, broadcast, subnet, hwaddr
```

в конце, получаю всего лишь `[], [], [], []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логическая ошибка в этой части кода:

```
...
if not addrs or addrs1:
    continue
...
```

Получается, что если `addr`==False ИЛИ `addr1`==True... Соответственно, если одна из переменных принимает значение `None`, то это всё равно прокатывает.

В общем, не хватает еще одного `not`:

```
...
if not addrs or not addrs1:
    continue
...
```

Ну, или:

```
...
if not (addrs and addrs1):
    continue
...
```

Comment: помогите также и с этим вопросом тогда [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501572/python-Удаление-из-вывода)
Благодорю